# How to use handwave library for Android studio?

Tags: android

I want to get hand gestures for my application.

I googled for this.Some one suggested Hand Wave library full fill this.

I get some sample code of Hand Wave by using the following link.

https://github.com/kritts/HandWave-Sample-Apps

I am trying to import those samples to Android studio.
 It shows error like

- Project HandsFreeGallery:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Kiran\HandWave-Sample-Apps-master\Gallery\project.properties:
  Library reference ......\Handsfree Interaction\Code\HandsFree-master\sdk\java could not be found
  Path is C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Kiran\HandWave-Sample-Apps-master\Gallery......\Handsfree Interaction\Code\HandsFree-master\sdk\java which resolves to C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Handsfree Interaction\Code\HandsFree-master\sdk\java

I don't know how to resolve this.

If any body know the solution.

Please help me.

Comment: you just need to click file->open->locate the sample click ok. thats it. if you getting any error while opening please post error log

Comment: How do you try to import? What steps do you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android Studio version. Someone forked the original project, and then made this one that works with AS. However, you will need to download OpenCV, and change the compile path in the AS library to the OpenCV that you downloaded and imported. 
https://github.com/Manishearth/HandWave/tree/androidstudio